# Solr/Lucene sentence analyze pulling out subjects

Tags: solr, lucene, text-analysis

Let's say I have documents with a free text field that is going to describe what type of branch a business will belong to:

example 1: "IT consulting with a focus on health-care solutions"

example 2: "Financial advising for online customers inside the United States"

What I would like to due with Solr or Lucene is pull out a taxonomy of business operations that are described in the text taking consideration to potential synonyms.  So the first example becomes a graph like:
  Information Technology  <-[in]-  Consulting  -[on]->  HeathCare

example 2 would be:
  Finance <-[in]-  Consulting

Operations like consulting or advising are synonyms depending on context.

Answer (score 1):

For synonyms, set up an analyzer to use a [SynonymFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory) and in the synonyms file, e.g.

```
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="business-synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
```

the file would look something like:

```
IT,information technology
advising,consulting
```

etc.  Though with 'IT' and case insensitivity it might expand the normal use of the word 'it', so you might need to experiment as to what works best with your data.

If the synonyms require context then it gets much more tricky.

---

Secondly, to only index the stuff you are interested in you can use a [KeepWordFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.KeepWordFilterFactory).  You would need to list all the words you are interested in indexing in a text file.

---

This setup will create an index for all the keywords you are interested in, including synonyms.  So you will be able to search for, say, a particular business type, e.g. 'IT consulting health care' and Solr would be able to retrieve matches for that using synonyms and its scoring system.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  Think my question shouldn't have mixed in Solr/Lucene rather NLP (natural language processing).  Need to extract nouns from a sentence (possibly correlate sentences) and even decorators (adjectives) to find the relations between business operations to form a business intention.